# How to delete uploaded jars from Nexus through command line

Tags: command-line-interface, nexus

While I understand that I can delete uploaded jars from Nexus through web interface, but is there a way in which the same operation can be done through CLI ? Am able to add jars through CLI but unable to remove them.

Comment: Just like a source code repository, artifacts are not designed to be deleted. what if a 3rd party build had a dependency on your module? Deleting it would break their build. Having said that Nexus has support for purging old snapshot versions, check out their scheduled jobs. Hope this explains why such a feature is not obviously available

Answer (score 2):

The REST API to delete artifacts from Nexus is a DELETE request to "/service/local/repositories//content/":

So for CLI you can use curl, and as an example this would be:

```
curl -X DELETE -u admin:admin123 http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/content/com/foo/bar/
```

Or you can delete the files directly from repository storage, see here for details:  [Can I directly update artifacts in Nexus local storage on disk?](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465608-Can-I-directly-update-artifacts-in-Nexus-local-storage-on-disk-)